# Wordpess. CSS. Скрыть элементы управления

Tags: css, wordpress

Добрый день!

Пожалуйста, подскажите как можно скрыть элементы управления (Title и Description) и сделать их не обязательными для создаваемого нового поста для конкретного list type? Я хочу чтобы пользователь использовал только metabox для ввода новых данных. Например: при добавлении новой машины в лист.

[image: Пример добавления нового поста]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо запустить свой файл стилей в админке. В `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'action_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function action_admin_enqueue_scripts( $hook_suffix ){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-admin-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-admin.css' );
}
```

Ну а в нем поставить `display: none;` ненужным элементам управления. Примерно так:

```
div#titlewrap {
    display: none;
}
div#postdivrich {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Добавил условие - поле title и description должны быть не обязательными. Мне не очень хочется вносить изменения на уровне кода (если это возможно). Опасаюсь, что при обновлении темы или плагинов написанный мною код может быть перезаписан.

Comment: А чем же вы хотите вносить эти изменения? Приведенный мной код никуда не денется при обновлениях, если будет размещен в functions.php дочерней темы.

Comment: я новичок в wordpress. При обновлении темы - файл functions.php не обновляется?  Я смог скрыть title с помощью css. Завтра пришлю описание реализации. Оно проще, чем предлагаемое вами. Зато столкнулся с другой проблемой. Поле title обязательное для заполнения. Я не хочу чтобы пользователь его вообще заполнял. Пока не знаю как это сделать в конкретном темплейте.

Comment: `function.php` не обновляется в ДОЧЕРНЕЙ теме. Поскольку на основе поля title генерируется постоянная ссылка, то скрыть его можно только в том случае, если код будет создавать сам постоянную ссылку для записи. Так что без кода тут не обойтись.

Comment: Я использовал Add Custom CSS и добавил правило `.cmb-row.cmb-type-text.cmb2-id-listing-title.table-layout{
display: none
}` Все работает без написания функций. Но есть другая проблема. Поле title обязательное для ввода на этой странице, а мне нужно сделать его необязательным

Comment: Я вам выше написал - его невозможно сделать необязательным

Comment: Сорри сразу не понял. Как быть ? При добавлении машин в лист это поле просто ненунжно. Можно ли его заполнять автоматически на последнем шаге работы Post шаблона ?

Comment: Фильтровать данные записи, например, с помощью фильтра wp_insert_post_data()